# How can i fill in missing csv file value base on reference csv file

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have a reference file like this

```
Id, Value1, Value2
a, a1, a2
b, b1, b2
c, c1, c2
d, d1, d2
...
n, n1, n2
```

and the missing file

```
Id, Value1, Value2
d,    , d2
g,    , g2
a, a1 , 
c, c1 , 
...
n,    , n2
```

how can i write the code to fill missing values based on reference file 'Id'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it using [fillna()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), but first set your joining column as index in both DF's:

```
In [71]: df = df.set_index('Id').fillna(ref.set_index('Id')).reset_index()

In [72]: df
Out[72]:
  Id Value1 Value2
0  d     d1     d2
1  g    NaN     g2
2  a    a1      a2
3  c    c1      c2
```

Data:

```
In [69]: ref
Out[69]:
  Id Value1 Value2
0  a     a1     a2
1  b     b1     b2
2  c     c1     c2
3  d     d1     d2

In [70]: df
Out[70]:
  Id Value1 Value2
0  d    NaN     d2
1  g    NaN     g2
2  a    a1     NaN
3  c    c1     NaN
```

Comment: @NaravutSuvannang, is that what you wanted?

Comment: got 'InvalidIndexError'

Comment: @NaravutSuvannang, could you post the whole error trace in your question?

Comment: Thanks, i think the error come from one space in the header.